# Why does this sequence generate all numbers in 2^n?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Here's a sequence, for fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$ j_{i+1} = (5 j_i + 1) \pmod{ 2^n} $$

This update rule can be simplified to:

$$ j_{i} = \frac{5^i - 1}{4} \pmod{ 2^n}$$

One can easily  verify  the above via  proof by induction.

Now when you start with $j_1 = 1$, you will eventually generate all numbers in the range $[2, 2^i]$ and then come back to 0 (in which case the term after is 1 again).

I wrote a quick python program to verify this:

```
ctr = 1
j = 1
exp = 20 # This is the n in 2^n
while j:
    j = ((5*j) + 1) % 2**exp
    ctr += 1

print("{} elements found.".format(ctr))
```

And up to `exp = 25` this works. Running the above gives us `1048576 elements found`.

I have a bit of knowledge in group theory, and from what this  looks like it's similar to the  intuition of cyclic groups. However, I can't  come  up  with a plausible  explanation for why this is true. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I also wanted to verify that indeed there were no duplicates, so I used a hashset for checking up to $2^{16}$ elements.

```
ctr = 1
j = 1
exp = 16

seen = set([1])

while j:
    j = ((5*j) + 1) % 2**exp
    ctr += 1
    if j in seen:
        print("DUPLICATE FOUND")
    seen.add(j)

print("{} elements found.".format(ctr))
```

And it appears that there were no duplicates either.

Comment: For $k \geq 3$, the subgroup $\langle 5 \bmod 2^k\rangle$ of the units mod $2^k$ is all integers mof $2^k$ that are $1 \bmod 4$: $\{5^j \bmod 2^k : j \geq 0\} = \{a \bmod 2^k : a \equiv 1 \bmod 4\} = \{1 + 4b \bmod 2^k : b \in \mathbf Z\}$. Therefore if you subtract $1$ from all these numbers and divide by $4$, you're going to get all integers modulo $2^{k-2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This answer is wrong. See KCd's comment on the main question for a correct solution.